# ActiveAdmin field rendered as select instead of boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a user form in my ActiveAdmin to manage a series of Booleans to partition off parts of my application based on them being true or not. This works pretty well. But two of my User boolean fields are rendered in the ActiveAdmin user edit screen as select menus instead of tick boxes.

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Admin Details" do
  ...
  f.input :super_admin, :label => "Super Administrator"
  f.input :account_manager
  f.input :sales_manager
  f.input :general_manager
  f.input :project_pipeline
  f.input :sales
  f.input :customers
  f.input :products
  f.input :price_lists
  f.input :project_action_plans
  f.input :projects

end
f.actions
```

end

[image]

I am failing to understand why this is happening. All I want is the two boolean fields (which are stored as boolean in my Postgresql database) to act as boolean fields on the page.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is that the `project_action_plans` and `projects` ? are those the two boolean  fields you talking about?

Comment: are you using `simple_form`?

Comment: Yes I am using simple_form and the fields are the 'project_action_plans' and 'projects'.

Comment: try forcing them. as in this way: `f.input :projects, as: :boolean`

Comment: forcing with as: :boolean renders an 'NoMethodError - undefined method `to_i' for #<ProjectActionPlan::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000005c23b20>:'

Comment: I think the issue might be that I am naming the columns the same as the name of some of my models pluralized. I am using the boolean field so I can easily switch a user to being able to see menus in the navigation and also authenticating them if they get routed to a part of the site they havent been authorised to enter. Maybe I should rename to 'projects_nav' or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by renaming the boolean fields to "authenticate_projects", "authenticate_project_action_plans" etc etc.

Now they are working as boolean fields and I can check them etc.

It seems that they activerecord association was somehow being applied to the field in the simple_form active_admin view so must have been trying to return the users projects or users project action plans so I would have a collection being input and so it would try and default it to the select box. Obviously without specifying which field from the collection to use as the value it was giving the dreaded # or whatever it is. And not 'dreaded' but I seem to hit this wall a lot so it dreads me.